# Unable to write html from windows batch script using for loop

Tags: html, windows, batch-file

after struggling for 2 days I still have not been able to find solution to my problem with windows batch script.

what I want to do is read the html file line by line and if the matching keyword found in a particular line, then replace that line with something (html tags and variable combination)

No matter whatever I do, I always get some error "**< was expected at this time**" whenever I try to push html tags to the file. Looks like batch script does not like html.

Here is my code:

script.bat

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7" %%i in (output.txt) do call :process %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o
goto :sendreport

:: procedure to prepare report

:process
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

    set UBENAME=%1
    set UBEVER=%2
    set UBESTAT=%3
    set RUNDATE=%4
    set STARTTIME=%5
    set ENDTIME=%6
    set TOTALTIME=%7

    SET FINDWHAT=%UBENAME%%UBEVER%  :: letter to find in the file
    SET REPLACEWITH=^<tr^>^<td^> %UBENAME% ^</td^>^<td^> %UBEVER% ^</td^>^<td^> %UBESTAT% ^</td^>^<td^> %RUNDATE% ^</td^>^<td^> %STARTTIME% ^</td^>^<td^> %ENDTIME% ^</td^>^<td^> %TOTALTIME% ^</td^>^</tr^>
    SET FILE=template.html  :: file to look in

    FINDSTR %FINDWHAT% %FILE% >nul
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO nowork

    MOVE /Y "%FILE%" "%FILE%.bak"
    FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "%FILE%.bak" ^|FIND /N /I "%FINDWHAT%"`) DO (
      SET LINE=%%A
    )
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=]" %%S in ("%LINE%") DO SET LINE=%%S  ::read file line by line
        SET /A LINE=%LINE:~1,6%
        SET /A COUNT=1
        FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`FIND /V "" ^<"%FILE%.bak"`) DO (
          IF "!COUNT!" NEQ "%LINE%" (
              ECHO %%A>>"%FILE%" :: if the matching string not found, write the line as it is
          ) ELSE (
              ECHO %REPLACEWITH%>>"%FILE%" :: if found, replace the entire line with PROPVAL
          )
          SET /A COUNT+=1
        )
    GOTO end
    :nowork

    :end
)
:sendreport
echo "done"
```

output.txt

```
R560359C    BA0001  Done    113121  24046   113121  24047
R560902C    BAS0006 Done    113121  24647   113121  45726
R560902C    BAS0005 Done    113121  24647   113121  45155
R560902C    BAS0009 Done    113121  45754   113121  70022
```

template.html

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr id='R560902CBAS0009'><td>R093021</td><td>BASJ1TNA</td><td>not_started</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr id='R6213G04BA0001'><td>R6213G04</td><td>BA0001</td><td>not_started</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr id='R560359BBA0001'><td>R560359B</td><td>BA0001</td><td>not_started</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr id='R560902CBAS0006'><td>R560902C</td><td>BAS0006</td><td>not_started</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr id='R560902CBAS0005'><td>R560902C</td><td>BAS0005</td><td>not_started</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr id='R560359CBA0001'><td>R560902C</td><td>BAS0009</td><td>not_started</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first, you cannot think comments on bat files are equal comments on another languages: if you put on same line of a command, it will be processed as a part of it...

Comment: Also, use "pause" command do "debug" (to discover where is the error) that kind of file...

Comment: Well, the issue is in `FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`FIND /V "" ^<"%FILE%.bak"`) DO (`... I'm trying to understand what is wrong...

Comment: `FIND /V "" ^<"%FILE%.bak"` has same effects as `FIND /V "" "%FILE%.bak"`...

Comment: Also, doing only `FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`FIND /V "" "%FILE%.bak"`) DO echo.%%A` it runs, showing a error inside the `for` loop...

Comment: Finally, remember about the use of `!` when using `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`. I think that was the issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7" %%i in (output.txt) do call :process %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o
goto :sendreport

:: procedure to prepare report

:process
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

    set UBENAME=%1
    set UBEVER=%2
    set UBESTAT=%3
    set RUNDATE=%4
    set STARTTIME=%5
    set ENDTIME=%6
    set TOTALTIME=%7

:: letter to find in the file
    SET FINDWHAT=%UBENAME%%UBEVER%
    SET REPLACEWITH=^<tr^>^<td^> %UBENAME% ^</td^>^<td^> %UBEVER% ^</td^>^<td^> %UBESTAT% ^</td^>^<td^> %RUNDATE% ^</td^>^<td^> %STARTTIME% ^</td^>^<td^> %ENDTIME% ^</td^>^<td^> %TOTALTIME% ^</td^>^</tr^>
:: file to look in
    SET FILE=template.html

    FINDSTR %FINDWHAT% %FILE% >nul
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO nowork

    MOVE /Y "%FILE%" "%FILE%.bak" >nul
    FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('TYPE "%FILE%.bak"') DO (
     ECHO "%%A"|FIND /i "%findwhat%" >NUL
     IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>"%file%" echo %%A
     ) else (
      >>"%file%" echo !replacewith!
     )
    )
GOTO :eof

:sendreport
echo "done"
GOTO :eof
```

This should do the job - if I understand what you're attempting to do by going all around the houses. Best to say whay the problem is rather than ask for a fix to a cure that doesn't work.

- Grab the file, line-by-line.
- Look for the target string
- if not found, just xerox the line
- if found, spit out the replacement line.

The trick being to use delayed-expansion to prevent the replacement line from being interpreted. With `!var!`, the parser doesn't know that the variable contains redirects, so it doesn't object. At execution time, the parser's already done its job.

Comment: Ok, it is more polite answer. I gave up on mine :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did the trick. I knew that !! delimeter used for runtime stuff but did not know that it canbe used like this, and parser does skip it. Thanks Peter, you saved me.